# Spring AuthenticationSuccessHandler autowired Service/DAO is null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am having a AuthenticationSuccessHandler which should hold a UserService. My problem is that i am getting a NullPointerException on the userService at this line:

```
logger.debug(userService.getAllUsers().toString());
```

AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl:

```
@Repository
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {         
        logger.debug(userService.getAllUsers().toString());

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);  
        response.sendRedirect("index"); 
    }
}
```

I Have also tried @Service and @Component Annotation but the same error.

It works in all other Services and Controller from my project but not in this Handler.

I also have this line of code in my config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.net4you.*" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

EDIT:
AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl is not created with new, but with:

```
   <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" 
authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.net4you.slamanagement.helper.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl"/>
```

Project structure:
[image: structure]

Debugger:
[image: Debugger]

Comment: You're probably create AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl  object with `new`. Can you post the Security configuration.

Comment: Do post your project / package structure along with configs.

Comment: updated post with all necessary information

Answer (score 4):

1) you dont need .*

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.net4you.*" />
```

this is enough

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.net4you" />
```

2) are you sure that userService is null?

3) configuration looks fine, maybe getAllUsers() method is returning null,
can you show its implementation?

**UPDATE**

You can solve this problem in two ways

1) remove

```
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.net4you.slamanagement.helper.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl"/>
```

and annotate AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl like this

```
@Component("customAuthenticationSuccessHandler")
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {         
        logger.debug(userService.getAllUsers().toString());

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);  
        response.sendRedirect("index"); 
    }
}
```

2) the second way would be creating setter of userservice in AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl , create userservice bean in xml manually and then inject it directly using setter property of authenticationSuccessHandlerImpl in xml, this solution is more complicated and i would suggest you to use first one

Your implementation doesn't work because you define a bean in xml without setting the userservice for it (@autowired doesn't work if you define bean manually) and then you inject this bean into form-login

Comment: I changed from com.net4you.* to com.net4you but still the same error. "logger.debug(userService.toString());" this line of code also gives a nullpointerexception and in my Controllers and Services userServie.getAllUsers() works fine an dont return me null.

Comment: @zFr3eak use debugger to check if userService is wired properly -> if yes then make you sure you autowire your service properly in your controller

Comment: how can i debug this ? I am using Spring tool suite.

Comment: Updated first post. UserService is deffinitly null!